# Facet Api Block Child Taxonomy Terms

Tags: search

I have products categories vocabulary containing the term T Shirts with child terms Polo & Round Neck.

I have created a facet api block to filter the results through those terms. Under Configure facet filters for Product category I have unchecked all the options.

Now when I am going on page with Facet API Block it's showing me a term T Shirts when I am clicking on T Shirts it shows me both the terms Polo & Round Neck but when I am clicking on Polo it disappears the Round Neck.

I am actually looking for option to display all the child terms even if one of them is selected.